# Query to select all IDs from a table that are non-existing IDs in the reference table?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT [USER_ID]
  FROM [DB].[dbo].[PhoneNumbers]
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT [USER_ID] FROM [DB].[dbo].[Users])
```

I am trying something like this, but I got stuck in the SQL server syntax.

I need to select all rows from the PhoneNumbers table that have User_IDs that DO NOT exist in the Users table so I can delete orphaned data.

Comment: So is this MySQL or SQL Server???

Comment: That query won't execute in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below query

```sql
SELECT [USER_ID]
FROM [DB].[dbo].[PhoneNumbers]
WHERE [USER_ID] NOT IN (SELECT [USER_ID] FROM [DB].[dbo].[Users])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to enclose a keyword as a table name in SQL Server, use [], and in MySQL use backticks.
Try Removing square braces and replace with backticks.

Answer (score 0):

Your query simply need a correlation clause:

```
SELECT [USER_ID]
FROM [DB].[dbo].[PhoneNumbers] p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [DB].[dbo].[Users] U WHERE u[USER_ID] = p.[USER_ID]);
```

I strongly, strongly recommend using `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN` with a subquery.  `NOT IN` does not behave as expected if the subquery returns *any* `NULL` values; in that case, no rows are ever returned.